# NetBeans 8.0.2 cross platform archetecture issues

Tags: git, macos, netbeans

I must be missing something and I hope you can help.  I have a C++ app that was initially developed using NetBeans on a RedHat x86 64 platform.  Both the code and `nbproject` files/folders are under source control (git).  Am also using Clang.

I am trying to port this application to OSX using the same version of NetBeans and adding a few `#ifdef` statements for the different platform differences.  I have also, on OSX, modified the per project NB properties to point to different include and lib locations and for the application's internal libs I point to the local `.../dist/Debug/Clang-MacOSX` dirs.

As I make the preference changes I hit the `Apply` button as often as possible.

Yet, when I compile the executable(s) and the final shared object(s) I get lots of messages about various C++ classes like `std::locale` and others and the message:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I do clean-and-builds every time.  I am ONLY using the `Debug` configs.  I have not touched the `Release` config options because for my needs I will only be deploying debug versions of this thing.

The `Release` configs DO still have references to x86_64 in them and the release related makefiles have x86 mentioned as do the various `configuration.xml` files.  I have been leery about ripping stuff out of these.

So, question is: how should I have setup Netbeans and git for cross platform C++ devel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was not obvious... turns out that I have to specify `-stdlib=libstdc++`.  It's all good not